# Combining multipe .dot files as one word file

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, macros

I need to combine two .dot files so that one X.dot file includes the macros from another Y.dot file. X.dot is for updating the header and footer, so that the right header/footer ist loaded and the Y.dot file contains multiple macros which are necessary vor replacing multiple variables in the text. I can't add or delete macros to the Y.dot  because this is protected by a password.

Is there a way to load the macros from one .dot to another?
Is there a possibility to add multiple .dot files to one word document?

Thanks

Comment: Can you verify how the Y.dot file is password protected? Are its macros not viewable?

Comment: I can still open the vba IDE but i can't open/view the macro's which are in the Y.dot file. besides that, the Y.dot file was bought from my Company from an external programmer. So I won't be legally able to Change the Y.dot file.

Comment: Sorry, I could not figure out a way to pull the macros without cracking the Y.dot file. However, you could base new documents off of the Y.dot, which would allow the macros to be run, and have the X.dot open, which would allow its macros to be run from your new document.